# How can I change Wakatime API Key in Sublime?

Tags: wakatime

I'm using Wakatime to log my work hours, I had to change my API Key and now I need to update the plugin in Sublime Text.

The [Wakatime FAQ](https://wakatime.com/help/getting-started/faq#leaderboard-vs-dashboard) sends me to the plugin repository, but I can't find any options there.

Comment: https://wakatime.com/faq#change-api-key

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Sublime Text, update your api key in your `WakaTime.sublime-settings` file.

[image]

This file can be found inside the `Packages` directory in Sublime Text, in my case, having MacOS it is in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/WakaTime` there I can find the said file.

There you can fill add your api key.

```
{
  api_key": "MY-WAKATIME-API-KEY",
  ...
}
```

#### More Generic Info

To view your api key: https://wakatime.com/settings/api-key

FAQ about api key: https://wakatime.com/faq#change-api-key